Oracle SQL bulk update based on CSV
Currently working over a Oracle DB, and need to update a specific field from a table called "USERS" This table contain main information, as the user name, ID, EMAIL, etc. We are updating all of our emails, so I need to update this table too.
So I have a list matching the user ID and their new email, so for that I want to know which should be the best way to achieve this bulk update?
I've been looking for and the main suggestion is to create another temporal table to allocate the new information (user ID, and new Email direction) and then just make the update by matching the Id from both tables and changing the email. Is this the best approach for this update? Or could be a better solution for it.
This is an example of how main table looks like. And the CSV file from which need to retrieve the new email and update it based on the user ID


Yep, that is the best way. Create a temp table, load it (easiest might be to create insert SQL using formulas in Excel, but SQL*Loader, MS Access, etc.. are also options), then do an update or merge on the main table.

If you have the right access you could also create an external table. If you look at generating statements from Excel then you could generate update statements, which would avoid the need to create a table.

I would go with the External Table option. Then you have all the power of SQL to do your updates
